# Convert string to a string method and assign it to a string

Tags: python

Is there a solution to convert `b` from the `string` to the string method `title()` and assign it to the variable `a`?

```
a = "car"
b = ".title()"
```

This is what I've tried using `eval()`:

```
>>> a = "car"
>>> b = ".title()"
>>> c = eval("car.title()")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> 
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module> 
NameError: name 'car' is not defined
```

Also tried the string method `format()`:

```
>>> a = "car"
>>> b = ".title()"
>>> c = "{0}{1}".format(a, b)
'car.title()'
```

What I would like to see as an output:

```
>>> "car".title()
'Car'
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: The easy solution would be just `eval(a+b)`, though I am confused as to why you want to do this.

Comment: `c = eval("'car'.title()")`

Comment: The *better* solution is to stop embedding Python code in string variables. `b = "title"; getattr("car", b)()`.